# Convert Facebook New Search to Graph or FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to convert this request

- https://www.facebook.com/search/110970792260960/events-near/

to a request that I can use with Facebook SDK, for example:

- https://graph.facebook.com/fql?access_token=X&q=SELECT ....

or

- search?type=event&center=Y&distance=Z

I've tried a FQL like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286441/list-of-all-facebook-events-in-a-given-location-in-the-last-two-years), unfortunately this query only return events **WITH** pages associated. I've tried filter the latitude and longitude from **venue** struct of [Event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) but again I need to specify the **?q=** parameter which reduces my results.

For the second option I can't because **parameters center and distance doesn't work with type=event**.

Answer (score 6):

FQL is deprecated and can only be used in older Apps, but you can use the search endpoint of the Graph API to search for events: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#search

Afaik this does NOT allow you to search for events in a specific area though. That´s just not possible with the API.

Comment: Yes FQL is deprecated, but I have a access token from a 2.0v APP that allow me send requests with FQL.

Comment: FQL only works with v2.0. you don´t need an access token, you only need an older v2.0 app. but it will only work until august 2016. after that, v2.0 and FQL will be gone. either way, you should not use it in new apps anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As @luschn said, FQL is deprecated and can be used until August 2016. There by theory a way to query for Page Events like this:

```
select 
    eid, 
    name, 
    description, 
    location, 
    all_members_count, 
    attending_count, 
    unsure_count, 
    not_replied_count, 
    declined_count, 
    start_time, 
    end_time,
    venue 
from 
    event 
where     
    creator in (
        select 
            page_id 
        from 
            place 
        where 
            distance(latitude, longitude, "37.76", "-122.427") < 1000
    ) 
and 
    start_time > "2015-05-22"
```

This only would include those events which have been created by a Page itself, and if the Page has an address stored. You can't get those Events created by Users, because you can't access their `location` field.